# Google static map shot showing up on page

Tags: html, image, google-app-engine, url-encoding, google-maps-static-api

I have a site built on the Google App Engine in Python. One of the features is the ability to use google static maps to update your current location. The Python code takes care of generating the URL of the static map and the HTML template simply puts it in place. This is what the space where the image should go looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"><img border=0 src="{{img_url}}" /></td>
</tr>
```

...and then here's how the image URL is generated:

```
self.template_values['img_url'] = "http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=%s,%s&zoom=%s&size=%s&markers=%s,%s,midreda" % (str(rs['lat']), str(rs['lng']), str(rs['zoom']), str(MAP_SIZE[0])+"x"+str(MAP_SIZE[1]), str(rs['lat']), str(rs['lng']))
```

The rs[] dict is the response from the google maps search. This generates a perfectly valid static map URL:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"><img border=0 src="http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=52.955115,-1.149172&zoom=11&size=512x512&markers=52.955115,-1.149172,midreda" /></td>
</tr>
```

The above image URL is after a search for 'Nottingham, UK'. If you visit the address you can see it shows up as intended, correct size and everything. However, on the page (which you can check at spare-wheels.appspot.com/searchlocation, although you need to connect your Facebook account to use it) the image doesn't show up. The HTML source looks fine: no apparent encoding problems or anything like that. I can't see what's gone wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks

Ben

EDIT: After a bit of testing I've found that the maps *sometimes* work but most of the time they don't, and when they work they generally stop working after a refresh

Comment: The `border` attribute on an image isn't valid HTML anymore, but if you do use it, put the 0 value in quotes.

Comment: This can be due to the lack of an API Key. Without the use of one, requests will be limited by a global shared limited quota of requests without API Keys. With one you'll be granted 25,000 free requests per day and you can sign your URLs to enable billing for additional quota. In Python you may use https://github.com/allrod5/staticmaps-signature to include your API Key and/or to sign your URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps API v1 is deprecated. The notice concerning free static map usage no longer needing an API Key is likely only valid to applications using Google Maps API V2.

Browser requests containing your referer are being denied with 403. Hence why it displays the broken image icon on your browser.

Either switch to v2 URL's, or supply an API key in the url.

Google provides an [upgrade guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/upgrade.html) for your convenience.

The correct v2 URL for your sample URL is:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=52.955115,-1.149172&zoom=11&size=512x512&markers=size:mid|color:red|label:A|52.955115,-1.149172&sensor=false
```

Notice these changes:

- Changed `/staticmap?` => `/maps/api/staticmap?`
- Added `sensor=false`
- Changed `markers` from `52.955115,-1.149172,midreda` to `size:mid|color:red|label:A|52.955115,-1.149172`

With all of the above the map displays correctly for me with the red marker, and should ensure Google recognizes your request as a V2 request.

Comment: I went through the upgrade guide, and changed my URL to this style: <img src="http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=52.955115,-1.149172&zoom=11&size=512x512&markers=size:mid|color:red|label:A|52.955115,-1.149172&sensor=false" /> but that just made the marker disappear. Is it possible the API isn't accepting v2 URLs from my app for some reason?

Comment: @kjy112: I think you mean the Javascript Maps API which is at v3. Static maps is only v2 still AFAIK.